# is there a php ready script to check mac addresses to the database

Tags: php, mysql, snmp

Is there a php script that will check the mac addresses of devices plugged into a switch(hp procurve) and compare it to the mac addresses saved in the PhpMyAdmin database?

I must use php to achieve this and i have not been able to find any answers.
I am also using snmp to try and achieve this.

Thank you 
.
.
.
.
Following the result of my question i should make the question clearer and give a background

I am doing a project and what is being asked of me is that : there is a database with a set of mac addresses stored. when a device plugs into my switch then i should be able to scan/check the mac addresses of that device to the mac addresses stored in the database. If there is a unknown mac address then an email is sent to the admin telling them which port and which mac address is unknown. and i must do this using php and mysql.

Comment: I am doing a project and what is being asked of me is that : there is a database with a set of mac addresses stored. when a device plugs into my switch then i should be able to scan/check the mac addresses of that device to the mac addresses stored in the database. If there is a unknown mac address then an email is sent to the admin telling them which port and which mac address is unknown. and i must do this using php and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

dot1qTpFdbTable in the Q-BRIDGE-MIB should have the MAC addresses you want.
You just need to walk that table.
I'm not aware of a script, but maybe this will get you further.

Comment: Thank You very much. i tried SNMPWALK 1.3.6.1.2.1.17..4.3.1.1 and it showed me the mac addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't .
The MAC address is not broadcast beyond the LAN the device is connected to it never leaves the router and passes to the server .